# Why spring task:annotation-driven exception-handler is not configured on the task:executor annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have two `task:executor` annotation:

```
<task:executor id="asyncExecutor"
               pool-size="5-100"
               keep-alive="120"
               rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"
               queue-capacity="1000"/>

<task:executor id="otherExecutor"
               pool-size="5-20"
               keep-alive="120"
               rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"
               queue-capacity="100"/>
<bean id="asyncExceptionHandler" class="com.xx.xx.xx.xx.common.AsyncExceptionHandler"/>

<task:annotation-driven executor="asyncExecutor" exception-handler="asyncExceptionHandler"/>
```

I want two `task:executors` to use the same `exception-handler`.
How can i do?

Comment: Just configure the `exception-handler`. It will be used for both, the `executor` you specify is the one used by default. You shouldn't have multiple `<task:annotation-driven />` elements as that has no use (one will override the other).

Comment: How to specify different exception handlers for different <task:executors>?